# Classifier does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here - kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting Classifier 'Child' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here. For below program

```
open class Parent constructor (name: String){
    val parentName: String = name
}
class Child : Parent("Amit"){
    fun printName(){
        print(parentName)
    }
}
fun main(agrs: Array<String>) {  
    Child child = Child()
    child.printName()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring your `child` variable in java style, the kotlin syntax would be

```
fun main(agrs: Array<String>) {  
    val child: Child = Child()
    child.printName()
}
```

or you can infer the type automatically

```
fun main(agrs: Array<String>) {  
    val child = Child()
    child.printName()
}
```